# Unable to Manually set Form Attributes with Crispy Forms

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I've been working on creating a model form with django-crispy-forms, with Django 1.8.4 and django-crispy-forms-1.5.2. I am failing to alter the form tag attributes.

I have tried setting `self.helper.form_tag = False`, but it still produces a `<form>` tag. I've tried setting other attributes like the `form_action`, but this does not work either, the form tag remains unchanged (the final HTML is still just `<form>`).

In the `views.py`:

```
class RegisterStudentView(CreateView):

    template_name = "register_student.html"
    model = Student
    form_class = StudentRegistrationForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboard')
```

In the `forms.py`:

```
class StudentRegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StudentRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        exclude = ['is_active', 'is_overdue', 'personid', 'tertiary_cell']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you have in your html template? It's possible the form tag is in there and not being generated by crispy-forms

Comment: Thanks @awwester, that was exactly my problem. There was a form tag surrounding my call to crispy forms.

Answer (score 2):

As awwester commented, the problem was having a hard coded `<form>` tag around the crispy forms function:

```
<form>
  {% crispy %}
</form>
```

Basically, crispy forms used the existing form tag and did not create the new one I wanted.